# Vuejs - list - How to pass click functions as string

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of objects, each with a `click` property (a string) that is passed to a `click`-event handler. I can print the `.click` property to the console, but it is not recognized as Vue data. I tried to `eval(todo.click)`, but it didn't work.

*html:*

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <label @click="clickMethod(todo)">{{todo.text}}</label>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <br>
  <div v-if="infoVisible">infoVisible</div>
  <div v-if="tresVisible">tresVisible</div>
</div>
```

*and my js:*

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    infoVisible:false,
    tresVisible:true,
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false, click:'infoVisible=!infoVisible' },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false, click:'infoVisible=!infoVisible' },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true , click:'infoVisible=!infoVisible'},
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true , click:'tresVisible=!tresVisible'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    clickMethod(todo){
      console.log(todo.click)
      todo.click()
    }
  }
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pflaho/ef97wn0q/3/)

Comment: You can't execute object string property as code in vuejs.

Comment: But you can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/oj25fbg9/, does this solve your problem ? If yes, i'll post it as answer.

Comment: Yes, it is what I did but I wished I could send some logic in the array.

Comment: @Culpepper proved me wrong, forgot the `eval` one :D

Comment: @Toodoo I do think my solution answers the question that was posed, however I personally would use the solution you suggested in https://jsfiddle.net/oj25fbg9/.

Comment: @Culpepper I think OP was posting dummy code, just for the example

Comment: even if you get the solution to this problem, it is still going to be a problem. the way you are doing things is an anti-pattern for the true nature of components.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using strings as functions (which would require [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)), you could define [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: (vm) => ({
    infoVisible: false,
    tresVisible: true,
    todos: [
      { ..., click() { vm.infoVisible = !vm.infoVisible } },
      { ..., click() { vm.infoVisible = !vm.infoVisible } },
      { ..., click() { vm.infoVisible = !vm.infoVisible } },
      { ..., click() { vm.tresVisible = !vm.tresVisible } },
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    clickMethod(todo){
      todo.click()
    }
  }
})
```

***Steps:***

1. In `todos[]`, change the type of `.click` properties from strings to function expressions:

   ```js
   //click: 'infoVisible = !infoVisible'  // from strings
   click() { infoVisible = !infoVisible } // to function expressions (to be updated in step 3)
   ```
2. In the function body, a reference to the Vue instance is required so that `click()` can change the data properties (i.e., `infoVisible` and `tresVisible`). Update the Vue declaration's `data` property to be a function that takes an argument (the argument will be the Vue instance itself):

   ```js
   data: (vm) => ({/* ... */})
   ```
3. Update `click()` to use that argument to reference the target data properties:

   ```js
   click() { vm.infoVisible = !vm.infoVisible }
             ^^^               ^^^
   ```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu0d57Lw/)

Answer (score 2):

eval(todo.click) will work but you need to add "this." to all of the todo properties in the click attributes so they have the right context, that is the context of the Vue instance.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    infoVisible:false,
    tresVisible:true,
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false, click:'this.infoVisible=!this.infoVisible' },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false, click:'this.infoVisible=!this.infoVisible' },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true , click:'this.infoVisible=!this.infoVisible'},
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true , click:'this.tresVisible=!this.tresVisible'},

    ]
  },
  methods: {
    clickMethod(todo){
          eval(todo.click)
        }
  }
})
```

Comment: **Security advice :** Be really carefull using `eval`, especially if your users can modify what's in the code executed by `eval`, you could be facing Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) issues. More infos : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!